# Setting text value based on slider value

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

Setting a text element based on slider value

I am trying to set a text element to a description of an emoji that is set by a slider. I have 5 different emojis set on a slider so the values are 0-4 since the list of emojis is an array. The text is not updating corrctly based on the code I have currently.

```
 const _emojis = ['','\u{1F928}','\u{1F610}','\u{1F612}',''];


            child: Slider(
                      value: _value,
                     // label: _emojis[_value.toInt()],
                      min: 0.0,
                      max: 4.0,
                      divisions: 4,
                      onChangeStart: (double value) {
                        print('Start value is ' + value.toString());                         
                      },
                      onChangeEnd: (double value) {
                        print('Finish value is ' + value.toString());
                        if(value.toString() == '0.0'){
                        return  _emotionalStatus = 'Happy';
                        }
                         if(value.toString() == '1.0'){
                        return  _emotionalStatus = 'Optimistic';
                        }
                          if(value.toString() == '2.0'){
                        return  _emotionalStatus = 'Neutral';
                        }
                          if(value.toString() == '3.0'){
                        return  _emotionalStatus = 'Pessimistic';
                        }
                          if(value.toString() == '4.0'){
                        return  _emotionalStatus = 'Sad';
                        }
                      },
                      onChanged: (double value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _value = value;
                        });
                      },
                      activeColor: Colors.white,
                      inactiveColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onChangeEnd` method , you don't need a return value, just call to setState after your conditions:

```
     onChangeEnd: (double value) {
              print('Finish value is ' + value.toString());
              if (value.toString() == '0.0') {
                 _emotionalStatus = 'Happy';
              }
              if (value.toString() == '1.0') {
                 _emotionalStatus = 'Optimistic';
              }
              if (value.toString() == '2.0') {
                 _emotionalStatus = 'Neutral';
              }
              if (value.toString() == '3.0') {
                 _emotionalStatus = 'Pessimistic';
              }
              if (value.toString() == '4.0') {
                 _emotionalStatus = 'Sad';
              }
              setState(() {

              });
            },
```